# What happened with lazy evaluation of Clojure

Tags: clojure, lazy-evaluation

I'm twisting my old java/python head the clojure way. Please help me to understand the lazy feature of clojure.

```
=> (def myvar (lazy-seq [1 2 (prn "abc")]))
#'user/myvar
```

The above is easy to understand. Since it's a lazy sequence, the (prn "abc") will not be evaluated, hence nothing printed.

```
=> (def myvar (lazy-seq [1 2 (prn undefined-var)]))
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: undefined-var in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1)
```

The above will raise an error as you can see. Why ?

My (wrong)understanding is, since it's lazy, the (prn undefined-var) could be legally here even the "undefined-var" has not been defined yet.

Please anyone point my understanding to the correct way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both above answers provide you with good information on the subject, but I'll try to pin down the key problem here. When you write an [s-expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression) on the REPL like `(+ x 2)` two things happen:

1. parsing by [the reader](http://clojure.org/reader) of the characteres which yields *forms*, such as symbols,
2. [evaluation](http://clojure.org/evaluation) of the forms.

Lazy evaluation pospones the second step, but in the first step, when reader encounters `undefined-var` it tries to convert it to a symbol, and finds that such symbol was not defined.

Comment: Thank you Pawel. It gets clearer. Source code need to be resolved to forms at reader's stage. The error simply shows the resolve process failed. Sounds like it's has nothing to do with the "lazy" evaluation stuff. Also it must be the common approach of all lisp dialect.

Comment: That's right. As far as I know, the reader is almost a mandatory part of any list dialect.

Answer (score 9):

When the clojure reader finds

```
 (def myvar (lazy-seq [1 2 (prn undefined-var)]))
```

It needs to compile it, that is the reason why it throws the error, as the undefined-var is not defined. In the first case, it compiles ok, but it is not executed until you consume the seq.

Comment: Is this just the case in Clojure because clojure script has to be compiled to java before executing ?  In other Lisp dialect, is it ok to use undefined var in a lazy evaluation context ?

Comment: Hi John, sorry but I don't have experience with other Lisps.

Comment: Thanks dAni, your answer helps a lot.But I can set only one as "accepted". Pawel's fit my brain more.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have the correct understanding, it just **thats not how the lazy-seq function works**
here is a typical example:

```
user> (lazy-seq (cons 4 (range 5)))
(4 0 1 2 3 4)
```

`lazy-seq` almost always takes a cons expression where the first argument
is the first item in the sequence and the second argument is the code
to produce the rest of the list. People verry rarely have to use lazy-seq 
directly in day to day Clojure, using forms like `map` `reduce`, `filter`,
etc. are much more common.

the code in the function for producing the rest of the sequence also neeeds 
to be able to be compiled, in your case you can delay compilation as well 
by using `eval` though I would recommend not using eval for things like this
in code others need to read; makes for great learning though ;-)

```
user> (def myvar (lazy-seq (cons 1 (eval '(prn undefined-var))))) ; don't do this at work
#'user/myvar
user> myvar
; Evaluation aborted.
user>
```